# Will double-track shelving work for a computer desk?

Tags: shelving, desk

I'd like to switch from using a computer desk to using double-track shelving.  The thing is that I'd need at least a 24" shelf for the desk part.  I see [they sell those brackets on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001D1X53E), but my computer alone is 55 lbs.  Would this solution be strong enough to support a couple monitors, a computer, a UPS, a printer, etc?

The tracks would be attached to studs with screws.  The studs are horizontal, so I'd be able to place my vertical tracks at any width.  I would be using wood shelves, or any other stronger material.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes.**  They can easily take the weight when anchored to studs.  I use it for my computer desk.  It works great and gives you a very inexpensive, height adjustable, and narrow depth desk.  I have two shelves.  One is 24" deep and is a keyboard/work surface.  The other is just 12" deep and holds my LCD monitor.

I opted to place just two rails ~32" apart (skipping one stud) so that my knees don't bang the brackets.  This causes the desktop to bow very slightly under the weight of my hands.  I suppose this could be fixed by using a more rigid surface vs. the default melamine shelving.

My PC is on the floor but these shelves could easily hold the weight.

Answer (score 2):

**Put your computer on the floor, where it belongs.** Same with the UPS. This opens up your desk space and muffles the noise.

The weight of LCD monitors and a printer won't be as much of a strain.

The strength of a shelf like this will depend a lot on how you attach it to the wall. Anchors in drywall hold a lot, but when they fail they leave an ugly hole and a big mess. Screwing directly in to a stud helps. Also, the track, the more the load appears as a vertical force, instead of a force trying pull the screw out of the wall. That's more reliable.

If you're not sure if your setup is strong enough, one way to approach the problem is to underbuild it, test it, then add on. So, you could put up a single track and load it with the full weight of the desk and equipment. If it holds, then put in the second rack, more screws, etc.

Comment: Computers on the floor get more dust than those on the desk. Also, I'm in a flood zone and this is ground floor on a slab.

Comment: I added more info about how I would be attaching it to the wall.

Comment: +1 but particularly for screwing directly into the stud. There are questions here about how you find the studs.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the computer on the floor, how about on a narrow shelf under/next to the desk part, for the computer, UPS, etc.

More than the connection to the wall, I'd worry more about the connection between the desk and the brackets.  Any force on the end of the desk will put a strain on this. I'd get the longest brackets that you can,  and make sure that they are securely attached to the desk.  You probably want to keep the heavy objects as close to the wall as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Rubbermaid makes brackets like the ones you describe: http://www.rubbermaid.com/Category/Pages/ProductDetail.aspx?CatName=ClosetShelving&SubcatId=WoodShelves&Prod_ID=RP091171 Their brand name is "Twin Track"

Their assembly instructions list a 275 lbs. load limit for a 24" deep bracket assuming the tracks are installed into studs and they recommend a bracket every 12"